# Is it possible to find maximum value of 2 or more column in a table?

Tags: jdbc, derby

for example : I have a table as follows

```
    id     math     science     english     history
    1       80        90           90         90
    2       70        60           81         78
    3       69        50           45         80
    4       30        40           10         80
```

i only want to find the maximum value in column math and science.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this :

```
select max(science),max(math) from your_table
```

Comment: thanks. it's working. turn out my earlier code were for maximum value of specific rows